# make the sent invoices as final invoice

Tags: php, vtiger

I want to make the changes for the invoices in vtiger as when the invoice status is changed to sent no one except the CEO have the priviliges to edit the invoice. So i want to remove the edit option from detail view.

i have edited the module/vtiger/view/detail.php and changed the code

```
$viewer->assign('IS_AJAX_ENABLED', $this->isAjaxEnabled($recordModel));
```

to

```
if($request->get('invoicestatus') === "Sent") {
   $viewer->assign('IS_AJAX_ENABLED', false);
   } else {
    $viewer->assign('IS_AJAX_ENABLED',$this->isAjaxEnabled($recordModel));}
```

but this do not change anything the detail view.Please let me know what to change here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make code changes. Make the invoices "private" or "public read only" in "access privileges" . Then create a workflow that assigns invoices to the CEO whenever the status changes to "Sent". That should accomplish your goal without changing the code.